# How to save and load new order of jquery sortable html elements within local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage, jquery-ui-sortable

My goal is to be able to save the new positions of jquery sortable html elements (i.e. some basic html cards), and on page refresh, obtain those saved positions from local storage and append them within a pre-existing html div. Allowing for the reordering of the html card positions to persist after browser refresh.

I am able to use the serialize method to save the serialized data of the card positions to local storage after sorting, and I'm even able to retrieve said data from local storage, but I am having trouble with applying that data back to the html elements.

I've read that sortable methods serialize or toArray might not even be the best approach to his problem.

Here is my code.

HTML

```
  <section id="cardFrameworkDashboard">
    <div id="cardDashboardRow" class="container-fluid cardDashboardRow">
      <div id="replaceDash" class="row mt-5">
        <div id="placementArea_0" class="cardPlacementArea fixed" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem" readonly>
          <div id="systemCard" class="card-body cardContent systemCard fixed" sortable="false">
            <div>HTML CARD 0</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="placementArea_1" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem;">
          <div id="card1" class="card-body cardContent card1" draggable="true">
            <div>HTML CARD 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="placementArea_2" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem">
          <div id="card2" class="card-body cardContent card2" draggable="true">
            <div>HTML CARD 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="placementArea_3" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem">
          <div id="card3" class="card-body cardContent card3" draggable="true">
            <div>HTML CARD 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="placementArea_4" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem">
          <div id="card4" class="card-body cardContent card4" draggable="true">
            <div>HTML CARD 4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="placementArea_5" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem">
          <div id="card5" class="card-body cardContent card5" draggable="true">
            <div>HTML CARD 5</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="placementArea_6" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem">
          <div id="card6" class="card-body cardContent card6" draggable="true">
            <div>HTML CARD 6</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="placementArea_7" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem; margin-top: 3rem">
          <div id="card7" class="card-body cardContent card7" draggable="true">
            <div>HTML CARD 7</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#replaceDash").sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var newSortOrder = $(this).sortable("serialize")
        var savedSortOrder = JSON.stringify(newSortOrder)
        localStorage.setItem("sortOrder", savedSortOrder)
        
        if (localStorage.getItem("sortOrder") !== null) {
          var arrayOfOrder = localStorage.getItem("sortOrder")
        } else {
          localStorage.clear
        }
      }
    })
    $(window).on("load", function() {
      var dashboard = $("#replaceDash")
      var cards = $("#replaceDash").children()
      // // grab data from ls
      var updatedSortOrderArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sortOrder"))
      // extract sort order and apply to HTML
      //clears html
      dashboard.empty() == ''
      // HOW DO I APPLY THIS DATA TO MY HTML
      for (var i = updatedSortOrderArray.length -1; i > 0; i--) {
        dashboard.prepend(newCards.get(updatedSortOrderArray))
      }
    })
    $('#replaceDash').disableSelection()
```

Comment: what;s the clear command for?  localStorage.clear

Comment: It might not be needed, but if the local storage is null, clear it. which would essentially do nothing

Comment: does sortOrder include a sorting definition, or an actual list of sorted items...it appears to me you have a definition object in updatedSortOrderArray and want to sort newCards and display it on the dashboard?  is that right

Comment: where is newCards defined?  should that instead say "cards"?

Comment: Yes newCards should be cards..... Also, yes you are correct with your previous comment. "sortOrder" is the key containing the value of whatever .sortable("serialize") gives me. I believe it is not an object of the newly sorted HTML elements themselves, but instead an array of the serialized data containing the order of the divs id's (i.e. placementArea_1. placementArea_3. placementArea_2, etc). I'm just trying to manipulate that data (if I even can) and create the new order of the HTML elements on the page from that.

Comment: when you changed to cards did it work?

Comment: No, they still reverted back to their original positions